# Version controlling bashrc, etc

Tags: version-control

I want to version control all the configuration files I have in my home directory on Linux machines. Files like

```
.bashrc
.bash_aliases
.bash_functions
.emacs
.gitconfig
.profile
```

Then I could just clone the repo into my home directory on any computers I had to do work on, and keep nifty emacs macros or bash functions I create up to date on all my servers. GitHub has a lot of features that make it an attractive solution for this, but I can't clone repos into existing directories, which is a problem.

What is a good way to manage these files across all the computers I use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291765/1870254 shows how to do this with git

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So the approach I use, and a lot of others use, is to have a dotfiles folder. In here you keep your .bashrc, .vimrc, etc. and create a repo of that folder. Clone this folder to all your machines, and soft link to the files using the `ln` command.

```sh
cd ~
mkdir dotfiles

mv .bashrc dotfiles/
#move other files

ln -s dotfiles/.bashrc .bashrc
#link other files

#do the git stuff
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to do the soft link on each machine for each dot file once, correct?

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Comment: And I have to delete/move the `~/.bashrc` and other dot files first from their original location, right?

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for and what the tool is. For a basic config file, yes. But for your `.bashrc`, if you want to keep it, you can just add `source /path/to/dotfiles/bashrc` at the end and it will handle both.