# Is there a way to version ~/.bashrc in-place by git, without copying to a different repo?

Tags: git

I'd like to version `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` using git, best if in-place (at the actual location), rather than creating a new repo and copy the file over and do the versioning there.

Is there a way to do that? I think the difficulty is, if I create a repo at `~`, it includes every folder in my home directory and is not desirable.

Is there some way to tell git: version *only* these files or folder, and disregard everything else and don't consider them to be submodules? If it can be like that, it might be a solution, except it seem like a super big repo to be at the home directory but at the same time ignoring almost everything.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a repo in another directory, and then use a symbolic link in your home directory (`~`) to point to the new file.

```
mkdir -p ~/path/to/repo
mv ~/.bashrc ~/path/to/repo/

cd ~
ln -s ~/path/to/repo/.bashrc .bashrc

cd ~/path/to/repo
# edit .bashrc
git init
git add .bashrc
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

This way, you have a plain repository that contains only the files you want to version control, and the rest of your system uses `~/.bashrc` as before, transparently following the link to the version controlled file.  No `.gitignore` or shell aliases needed.

Comment: so you always have to remember what that repo folder is and and go there and do the git commands? And (2) it treats the symbolic link as an actual file in the repo?

Comment: `ls -l .bashrc` will show you where the symbolic link points to, so you don't have to remember.  But yes, you will perform the git commands in that directory.

Comment: The contents of the symbolic link are basically a string with the path to the target file, but the system will interpret the link file as if it were a real file (the target file).  https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe and Wikipedia have good info on the subject.

Comment: it seemed to work, except it probably needs to be `ln -s ~/.bashrc ~/path/to/repo/.bashrc`  The `~` in `~/.bashrc` is important or else it links to `.bashrc` of the current folder, it seems

Comment: actually, I did `more .bashrc` in that repo and it seems to show the proper content, but if I go to GitLab (or GitHub if you want) and look at that file, it merely shows a link

Comment: It always pays to double check the man page before making a symbolic link.  It creates a confusing situation if you get it backwards, which is easy to do.  `ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)`.  In your case, you'll want to move the existing `~/.bashrc` to your repo directory, commit it, and then make the link.

Comment: oh... like that...? Then I don't like it as my system depends on a repo...

Comment: It's just a suggestion, and one that works well for me.  I'm not sure I understand the concern.  Your goal is to version control your dot file, so your system will depend on a repo no matter which strategy you choose.  Symbolic links are also a great tool for moving files to directories that are automatically backed up, or mounted over a network, etc.

Comment: I'd rather the system works well without the repo, and just copy the .bashrc to a repo to version it occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

The [bare repo approach](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) is another option:

> No extra tooling, no symlinks, files are tracked on a version control system, you can use different branches for different computers, you can replicate you configuration easily on new installation.
>
> The technique consists in storing a Git bare repository in a **"side" folder** (like `$HOME/.cfg` or `$HOME/.myconfig`) using a specially crafted alias so that commands are run against that repository and not the usual `.git` local folder, which would interfere with any other Git repositories around.

Coupled with the alias

```
alias config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg/ --work-tree=$HOME'
config config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no
```

You then add only the files you want:

```
config add .vimrc
```

Comment: can this approach `git push` to gitlab and/or github?

Comment: Yes, it can. Simply add a remote url to that side repository, and push.

Answer (score 2):

You could try gitignore.

```
cd ~
git init
echo '*' >> .git/info/exclude
echo '!.bashrc' >> .git/info/exclude
git add .bashrc
git commit -m'foo'
```

The patterns ignore all except `.bashrc`.

```
*
!.bashrc
```

Comment: it looks like I can use a `.gitignore` too? oh... but then since it is my home directory, it can have effect to all my other repo

Comment: @nonopolarity  Yes, `.gitignore` is also okay. It does not have effect to all your other repos. One of the differences between `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` is that the former can be committed as part of the source files (you can choose not to by ignoring `.gitignore` itself) and the latter can't.

Comment: is it true "`~/.gitignore` applies to all the repositories on your computer (local, not shared with others)." https://stackoverflow.com/a/22906950/325418

Comment: @nonopolarity yes, you are right. I forgot that it's `~/.gitignore`.

Comment: your solution seems to work best, but there is also something dangerous: in some folders under my home directory, I am seeing it treats it as part of the repo, and always telling me my `~/.bashrc` has uncommitted change. It feels really dangerous to have my home directory and every subfolder to be a giant repo constantly and if by any accident, I can be add or pushing files to the Internet, publicly, even my `~/.ssh/` private keys (if by any accident)

Comment: For example, `create-react-app` is doing some `git` commands... I don't want any public script doing things under my `~/sourcecode` while my `~` is a git repo as seen in `~/sourcecode/react-app-01`. A react app that says "hello world" has 300MB of source code, and with massive amount of scripts... I really can't tell what they really are doing. When something doesn't work, I can google it. *But* when it adds everything to the repo and with me `git push` to the Internet, that's not good

Comment: @nonopolarity You are right. It's a bad practice to initialize the home directory as a git repository. It could be annoying, and dangerous as you have realized. Don't insist on a git approach to this task.

Comment: I guess one way is for me to have an alias or a function, so that I can do something like `cp ~/.bashrc ~/bashrc-repo && cd ~/bashrc-repo && git com -am "ok" && git push && cd -`

Comment: That alias might be all you want, though `git diff` won't tell you if there have been any changes, or what they are, until you manually copy the file to the repo directory.

Comment: @nonopolarity https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152733/bashrc-in-custom-folder might help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Simple Revision Control [SRC](http://www.catb.org/~esr/src), a simple modern version control system for managing individual files (not collections of files changed in lockstep). Or look for the granddaddy of them all, Revision Control System [RCS](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs) (probably even available as an official package for your favorite Linux distribution).

Fluff trivia of the day, not too long ago IBM's AIX code was managed with RCS (perhaps still as of today, that came out in the SCO vs IBM lawsuit).

Comment: is this a lightweight version control system... can it push to something just in case of hard drive issue?  It probably is not aimed to replace git, right?  `git` something is difficult to use with all those rebase and git stash complicated operations (to get really good by reading a book, it is a book with 450 pages)

Comment: @nonopolarity, SRC handles git's fast-import and fast-export protocols, so you can send stuff offsite (never fiddled with that, though). It's repository format is just a hidden directory called `.src` with a file containg all history for each managed file in the current directory.